# Java ToolTipText ClassCastException

Tags: java, tooltip, classcastexception

i'm programming in IntelliJ IDEA, and when i add a ToolTipText to any Component (e.g. a JLabel), start the Program, and hover the Component, i get the following error:

> Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ClassCastException:
>   javax.swing.JScrollPane$ScrollBar cannot be cast to
>   javax.swing.JToolTip  at
>   javax.swing.plaf.synth.SynthToolTipUI.paint(SynthToolTipUI.java:179)
>     at
>   javax.swing.plaf.synth.SynthToolTipUI.update(SynthToolTipUI.java:141)
>     at javax.swing.JComponent.paintComponent(JComponent.java:778)   at
>   javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1054)    at
>   javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(JComponent.java:887)     at
>   javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1063)    at
>   javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(JComponent.java:887)     at
>   javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1063)    at
>   javax.swing.JLayeredPane.paint(JLayeredPane.java:586)     at
>   javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(JComponent.java:887)     at
>   javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1063)    at
>   javax.swing.JComponent.paintToOffscreen(JComponent.java:5222)     at
>   javax.swing.RepaintManager$PaintManager.paintDoubleBuffered(RepaintManager.java:1572)
>     at
>   javax.swing.RepaintManager$PaintManager.paint(RepaintManager.java:1495)
>     at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paint(RepaintManager.java:1265)   at
>   javax.swing.JComponent._paintImmediately(JComponent.java:5170)    at
>   javax.swing.JComponent.paintImmediately(JComponent.java:4981)     at
>   javax.swing.RepaintManager$4.run(RepaintManager.java:824)     at
>   javax.swing.RepaintManager$4.run(RepaintManager.java:807)     at
>   java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)    at
>   java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:75)
>     at
>   javax.swing.RepaintManager.paintDirtyRegions(RepaintManager.java:807)
>     at
>   javax.swing.RepaintManager.paintDirtyRegions(RepaintManager.java:782)
>     at
>   javax.swing.RepaintManager.prePaintDirtyRegions(RepaintManager.java:731)
>     at javax.swing.RepaintManager.access$1300(RepaintManager.java:64)   at
>   javax.swing.RepaintManager$ProcessingRunnable.run(RepaintManager.java:1720)
>     at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:311)
>     at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:749)   at
>   java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)    at
>   java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:702)    at
>   java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:696)    at
>   java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)    at
>   java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:75)
>     at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:719)   at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
>     at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
>     at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
>     at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
>     at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
>     at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
>   Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ClassCastException:
>   javax.swing.JScrollPane$ScrollBar cannot be cast to
>   javax.swing.JToolTip  at
>   javax.swing.plaf.synth.SynthToolTipUI.paint(SynthToolTipUI.java:179)
>     at
>   javax.swing.plaf.synth.SynthToolTipUI.update(SynthToolTipUI.java:141)
>     at javax.swing.JComponent.paintComponent(JComponent.java:778)   at
>   javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1054)    at
>   javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(JComponent.java:887)     at
>   javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1063)    at
>   javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(JComponent.java:887)     at
>   javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1063)    at
>   javax.swing.JLayeredPane.paint(JLayeredPane.java:586)     at
>   javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(JComponent.java:887)     at
>   javax.swing.JComponent.paintToOffscreen(JComponent.java:5229)     at
>   javax.swing.RepaintManager$PaintManager.paintDoubleBuffered(RepaintManager.java:1572)
>     at
>   javax.swing.RepaintManager$PaintManager.paint(RepaintManager.java:1495)
>     at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paint(RepaintManager.java:1265)   at
>   javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1040)    at
>   java.awt.GraphicsCallback$PaintCallback.run(GraphicsCallback.java:39)
>     at
>   sun.awt.SunGraphicsCallback.runOneComponent(SunGraphicsCallback.java:79)
>     at
>   sun.awt.SunGraphicsCallback.runComponents(SunGraphicsCallback.java:116)
>     at java.awt.Container.paint(Container.java:1973)    at
>   java.awt.Window.paint(Window.java:3901)   at
>   javax.swing.RepaintManager$4.run(RepaintManager.java:835)     at
>   javax.swing.RepaintManager$4.run(RepaintManager.java:807)     at
>   java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)    at
>   java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:75)
>     at
>   javax.swing.RepaintManager.paintDirtyRegions(RepaintManager.java:807)
>     at
>   javax.swing.RepaintManager.paintDirtyRegions(RepaintManager.java:782)
>     at
>   javax.swing.RepaintManager.prePaintDirtyRegions(RepaintManager.java:731)
>     at javax.swing.RepaintManager.access$1300(RepaintManager.java:64)   at
>   javax.swing.RepaintManager$ProcessingRunnable.run(RepaintManager.java:1720)
>     at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:311)
>     at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:749)   at
>   java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)    at
>   java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:702)    at
>   java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:696)    at
>   java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)    at
>   java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:75)
>     at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:719)   at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
>     at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
>     at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
>     at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
>     at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
>     at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
>   Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ClassCastException:
>   javax.swing.JScrollPane cannot be cast to javax.swing.JToolTip    at
>   javax.swing.plaf.synth.SynthToolTipUI.paint(SynthToolTipUI.java:179)
>     at
>   javax.swing.plaf.synth.SynthToolTipUI.update(SynthToolTipUI.java:141)
>     at javax.swing.JComponent.paintComponent(JComponent.java:778)   at
>   javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1054)    at
>   javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(JComponent.java:887)     at
>   javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1063)    at
>   javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(JComponent.java:887)     at
>   javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1063)    at
>   javax.swing.JLayeredPane.paint(JLayeredPane.java:586)     at
>   javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(JComponent.java:887)     at
>   javax.swing.JComponent.paintToOffscreen(JComponent.java:5229)     at
>   javax.swing.RepaintManager$PaintManager.paintDoubleBuffered(RepaintManager.java:1572)
>     at
>   javax.swing.RepaintManager$PaintManager.paint(RepaintManager.java:1495)
>     at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paint(RepaintManager.java:1265)   at
>   javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1040)    at
>   java.awt.GraphicsCallback$PaintCallback.run(GraphicsCallback.java:39)
>     at
>   sun.awt.SunGraphicsCallback.runOneComponent(SunGraphicsCallback.java:79)
>     at
>   sun.awt.SunGraphicsCallback.runComponents(SunGraphicsCallback.java:116)
>     at java.awt.Container.paint(Container.java:1973)    at
>   java.awt.Window.paint(Window.java:3901)   at
>   javax.swing.RepaintManager$4.run(RepaintManager.java:835)     at
>   javax.swing.RepaintManager$4.run(RepaintManager.java:807)     at
>   java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)    at
>   java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:75)
>     at
>   javax.swing.RepaintManager.paintDirtyRegions(RepaintManager.java:807)
>     at
>   javax.swing.RepaintManager.paintDirtyRegions(RepaintManager.java:782)
>     at
>   javax.swing.RepaintManager.prePaintDirtyRegions(RepaintManager.java:731)
>     at javax.swing.RepaintManager.access$1300(RepaintManager.java:64)   at
>   javax.swing.RepaintManager$ProcessingRunnable.run(RepaintManager.java:1720)
>     at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:311)
>     at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:749)   at
>   java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)    at
>   java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:702)    at
>   java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:696)    at
>   java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)    at
>   java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:75)
>     at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:719)   at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
>     at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
>     at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
>     at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
>     at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
>     at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
>   Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ClassCastException:
>   javax.swing.table.JTableHeader cannot be cast to javax.swing.JToolTip
>     at
>   javax.swing.plaf.synth.SynthToolTipUI.paint(SynthToolTipUI.java:179)
>     at
>   javax.swing.plaf.synth.SynthToolTipUI.update(SynthToolTipUI.java:141)
>     at javax.swing.JComponent.paintComponent(JComponent.java:778)   at
>   javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1054)    at
>   javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(JComponent.java:887)     at
>   javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1063)    at
>   javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(JComponent.java:887)     at
>   javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1063)    at
>   javax.swing.JLayeredPane.paint(JLayeredPane.java:586)     at
>   javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(JComponent.java:887)     at
>   javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1063)    at
>   javax.swing.JComponent.paintToOffscreen(JComponent.java:5222)     at
>   javax.swing.RepaintManager$PaintManager.paintDoubleBuffered(RepaintManager.java:1572)
>     at
>   javax.swing.RepaintManager$PaintManager.paint(RepaintManager.java:1495)
>     at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paint(RepaintManager.java:1265)   at
>   javax.swing.JComponent._paintImmediately(JComponent.java:5170)    at
>   javax.swing.JComponent.paintImmediately(JComponent.java:4981)     at
>   javax.swing.RepaintManager$4.run(RepaintManager.java:824)     at
>   javax.swing.RepaintManager$4.run(RepaintManager.java:807)     at
>   java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)    at
>   java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:75)
>     at
>   javax.swing.RepaintManager.paintDirtyRegions(RepaintManager.java:807)
>     at
>   javax.swing.RepaintManager.paintDirtyRegions(RepaintManager.java:782)
>     at
>   javax.swing.RepaintManager.prePaintDirtyRegions(RepaintManager.java:731)
>     at javax.swing.RepaintManager.access$1300(RepaintManager.java:64)   at
>   javax.swing.RepaintManager$ProcessingRunnable.run(RepaintManager.java:1720)
>     at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:311)
>     at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:749)   at
>   java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)    at
>   java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:702)    at
>   java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:696)    at
>   java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)    at
>   java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:75)
>     at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:719)   at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
>     at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
>     at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
>     at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
>     at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
>     at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)

I add the Tooltip with this line:

```
lblDrop.setToolTipText("testLabeltest");
```

What does this mean?

Thanks for helping :)

Comment: Show how you add ToolTip. It looks that not ToolTip was added.

Comment: i updated my request with the code

Comment: Are you sure that lblDrop is jLabel? Your stack says "javax.swing.JScrollPane$ScrollBar cannot be cast to javax.swing.JToolTip " which means that some inner class is treated as JToolTip which means there is a mess with classes and variables. Please, provide minimal functional example.

Comment: Yes it is a JLabel. Or is it maybe cause the Label is meant to interact as a Droptarget? But if so, the other components must run correctly